# chaining gulp tasks and passing variables

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to build up a gulp task which sorts my javascript files into the proper order before concatenating them.

This means 1-> get the installed bower components, 2-> sort the components into the include order, 3-> pass the sorted array of files to the concat method.

So far, I've managed this

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var dependency_orderer = require('dependency-orderer');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var bower_list, depend_array, js_depend_array;
gulp.task('order-dependencies',['get-bower-list'], function(){
    console.log(bower_list);
 //   depend_array = dependency_orderer(bower_list);
    //console.log(depend_array);
//    return depend_array;
});

gulp.task('get-bower-list', function(){
    exec('bower list -p', function(err, stdout, stderr){
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        bower_list = stdout;
        console.log(bower_list);
        return bower_list;
    });

});
gulp.task('concat-files',['order-dependencies'], function(){


});
```

But the problem is that I can't seem to get my `bower_list` in the `order-dependencies` task.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the task finishes without waiting for the async call you make ( the `exec(...)` ). So the variable is still `undefined` when you read it in the 2nd task.

Try using the callback to define when your task ends

```
gulp.task('get-bower-list', function(done){
    exec('bower list -p', function(err, stdout, stderr){
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        bower_list = stdout;
        console.log(bower_list);
        return done();
    });
});
```

and you can also use promises to define when tasks are 'done'

see the [API docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support)